# Calling the Camera Apps (Permission Denial: starting Intent )

Tags: android, android-camera, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-camera-intent

My fragment is trying to start Camera Activity, but it seems like there is some camera permission problem,

while debugging it goes till below line of code only

```
startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Below is the logcat result

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.example.tc.provider/external_files/Pictures/photo_saving_app/IMAGE_20191205_070208.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{8920903 18662:com.example.tc/u0a343} (pid=18662, uid=10343) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2016)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1962)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4452)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1617)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4551)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
```

Following is the part of code That seems required.

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) { //use this if Lollipop_Mr1 (API 22) or above
            Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();
            callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            // We give some instruction to the intent to save the image
            File photoFile = null;

            try {
                // If the createImageFile will be successful, the photo file will have the address of the file
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                // Here we call the function that will try to catch the exception made by the throw function
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Exception error in generating the file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Here we add an extra file to the intent to put the address on to. For this purpose we use the FileProvider, declared in the AndroidManifest.
            Uri outputUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    getActivity(),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    photoFile);

            callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

            // The following is a new line with a trying attempt
            callCameraApplicationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Calling the camera App by intent");

            // The following strings calls the camera app and wait for his file in return.
            startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Manifest file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tc">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <!--
    Allows Glide to monitor connectivity status and restart failed requests if users go from a
    a disconnected to a connected network state.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="Login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It was working fine previously. I might have done some silly mistake as I am just a learner with help of internet only.

Answer (score 10):

As per the [`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> Note: if you app targets M and above and declares as using the `Manifest.permission.CAMERA` permission which is not granted, then attempting to use this action will result in a `SecurityException`.

You do not need the camera permission to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` on any API level. Therefore, if you are only using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you can remove the line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`.

If you are using the Camera APIs in addition to using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you must [request the permission at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

While debugging it comes on last line and error occurs...

Comment: So, no more SecurityException? Each question on StackOverflow should contain just a single question, so if you're now farther along and encountering a new problem, you should try debugging that and then ask a new question with the failing code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake we have requirements that needs `CAMERA` for video call & we're using an image cropping library that uses `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. This cause the app to crash when tried to use the library with the ff. error

`Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list hasLabel(0) {U(content)}} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{65880b 3431:com.sample.sample/u0a148} (pid=3431, uid=10148) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA`

Any solution for this case? Thanks

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS - if your app does specify the CAMERA permission in your manifest at all because you are using it elsewhere in your app, then it must be granted before you can use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. It is only not required if you don't declare it in you manifest at all, as per the last paragraph in my answer, which specifically points this out.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks I will try it, I think the key is to request the `CAMERA` permission first before using the library that uses `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Currently we are only requesting the camera for video calling and not for the image cropping library.